# Admin Top Bar Not Showing On Front End Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm having problem with displaying admin top bar on my site.
I googled and got some solution which i tried like
 
1) Checking wp_footer in footer.php
2) Checkbox ticked in user profile saying show toolbar will viewing site.

All done but no success. please can anyone point me in right direction. 
I'm using Classicraft theme.

I'm using wordpress 3.8.3

I have another wordpress installation on same server and can see admin bar their but not on this site. is this theme specific problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in your PHP logs or the browser console?

Comment: check your functions.php for show_admin_bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution thanks to chyupa.

I searched show_admin_bar in my function.php and files included in that and found

```
    function my_function_admin_bar() {
    return false;
}

    add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

i just removed that function and my admin bar appeared.

Thank you hobo for replying.